# How to use Generic interface with two type in return of method

Tags: c#, generics, generic-constraints, generic-interface, generic-type-parameters

I need to create an interface with 2 type and use it as a method return value.

```
public interface StringLong<T1,T2>
where T1 : string
where T2 : long
{}

StringLong<T1,T2> method StringLong<T1,T2>()
```

Comment: @OlivierRogier : method's output is sometimes string and sometimes long or maybe other types in future.

Comment: @OlivierRogier - Good question. I'd hope the OP could answer that soon.

Comment: @OlivierRogier - Please avoid editing other people's answers and adding information. It's up to the author to decide to add information. Instead it's best to post the request for additional information as a comment.

Comment: I know we can use dictionary or tuple but I need use generic interface

Comment: The "I need to" argument is bit weak. Can you please explain why you think that?

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to define an interface with two generic types that you constrain to just `string` and `long`.

It sounds like you just want a tuple:

```
(string, long) MyMethod()
{
    return ("Hello", 42L);
}
```

You can even name the return values:

```
(string message, long meaningOfLife) MyMethod()
{
    return ("Hello", 42L);
}
```

Then you can write:

```
var result = MyMethod();
Console.WriteLine(result.message);
Console.WriteLine(result.meaningOfLife);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is the functionality you are trying to achieve (from the comments). Since the return might be of either `string` or `long` there common ancestor is `object`.

Once you have the value you can use pattern matching to cast the result into the appropriate type:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = MethodReturnsStringOrLong(1722);
        switch (obj)
        {
            case string str:
                Console.WriteLine($"String is {str}");
                break;
            case long lng:
                Console.WriteLine($"Long is {lng}");
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    public static object MethodReturnsStringOrLong(int input)
    {
        if (input % 2 == 0)
        {
            return 1928374028203384L;
        }
        else
        {
            return "ASIDJMFHSOASKSJHD";
        }
    }
}
```

---

An alternative is the create your own common ancestor, like the class `Value` below that might contains either a `long` and/or a `string`.

```
public class Value
{
    public Value(long longValue)
    {
        LongValue = longValue;            
    }
    public Value(string stringValue)
    {
        StringValue = stringValue;
    }

    public long? LongValue { get; }
    public string StringValue { get; }
}


static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = MethodReturnsStringOrLong(1722);
        if (obj.LongValue.HasValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Long is {obj.LongValue.Value}");
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.StringValue))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"String is {obj.StringValue}");
        }
    }

    public static Value MethodReturnsStringOrLong(int input)
    {
        if (input % 2 == 0)
        {
            return new Value(1928374028203384L);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Value("ASIDJMFHSOASKSJHD");
        }
    }

}
```